# Garbage value with post increment

Tags: c

Question 1

```
int x;
if (x++)
  {
    printf ("\nASCII value of X is smaller than that of x");
  }
```

Is `x` assigned here with a garbage value ??

Question 2:

```
main ()
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i++ < 10;)
    {
      printf ("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how `i++ < 10` works?I mean it should end at 9 why 10

Comment: Only one question per question, please :)

Comment: @Thomas Sorry , but no.Have a lot of such small queries ..

Comment: @YRT92 Please learn to use curly braces for your `if`, `while`, `do .. while`, and `for` statements, even if you intend to only have one line of code follow them.  It will save you many hours of debugging grief, one day.

Comment: Google increment operator instead of asking SO what it does.

Comment: We don't mind helping out with homework, but please just ask one question at a time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first question, you declare x

```
int x;
```

but you do not assign it, this reserves some memory to hold the value of x, but doesn't initialize it to a known value.  That's a really bad thing.  Then you read it, increment it, and possibly do something.

```
if ( x++ ) {
  printf ( "\nascii value of X is smaller than that of x" ) ;
}
```

Since you don't know what it's value was before you read it, it is impossible to make an educated guess as to whether your if statement will print anything.

In your second question (please one question per question), you read the value of i, then increment it, and then do the comparison on the read value.  Post increment basically means, "increment the value *after* I read it" and so the new value will be stored, then the comparison made on the old value, and the printf statement below will print the "current, new" value.

Comment: it should end at 9 but why 10?

Comment: It does end at the read value of 9, but since the increment happens _after_ the read, the stored value is 10 after you read the value 9 within the `if` statement.  The printf line below re-reads the value, which is now 10 (because it is reading it after the check in the `if` statement)

Comment: "One question per question" :):):) Lovely!

Answer (score 2):

1. The value of `x` is *indeterminate*, and is possibly a trap representation, in which case the behavior of `x++` is undefined.
2. The expression `i++` *evaluates* to the current value of `i`; as a *side effect*, the value in `i` is incremented.  So if `i` == 1, the expression `i++` will evaluate to 1, and as a side effect `i` will be set to 2.

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> #### 6.5.2.4 Postﬁx increment and decrement operators
>
> ...
> 2 The result of the postﬁx `++` operator is the value of the operand. **After the result is
> obtained, the value of the operand is incremented**. (That is, the value 1 of the appropriate
> type is added to it.) See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment
> for information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
> pointers. The side effect of updating the stored value of the operand shall occur between
> the previous and the next sequence point.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: I think [the increment is done before the comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_operators#Operator_precedence)

Comment: @m0skit0: No.  *Precedence* does not control order of evaluation, nor does it control when side effects are applied.  See my edit above.

Comment: You're right, i++ is post-increment, **but** *precedence* indeed controls order of evaluation. It's what it is for, or I'm missing something here.

Comment: @m0skit0: 6.5/3: "The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.74)
Except as speciﬁed
later (for the function-call `()`, `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and comma operators), the order of evaluation
of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspeciﬁed."  Also note that operands for `||` and `&&` are evaluated strictly left-to-right, regardless of precedence (for `a || b && c`, `a` will be evaluated before `b`, which will be evaluated before `c`, even though `&&` has higher precedence than `||`).

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Yes

Question 2: Yes. i is incremented by one then compared if it's lesser than 10.